# Magento2 - How to update configurable product price based on date selection with color, size etc attributes?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price

In Magento2 Configurable Product Page I want to update price based on attribute change like `color`, `size` etc. with custom field **FROM DATE** and **TO DATE** selection.

**NOTE: (by default Magento provides with configurable options like `size`, `color` etc.).**

I have attached the screen shot also : [image]

When I change dates then changes should be done including to `size` and `color` based price too, but it responses with the addition of **PRODUCT MAIN PRICE**

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

[image]By default magento 2 provide that option. During configuration product , on the third step u can choose "Apply unique prices by attribute to each SKU" and assign unique price for your super attribute

Update:
Added more SC for your clarification

[image]

[image]

Comment: By this way It should not be possible, we applied your answers...Thank you :(

Comment: We need from front end. I think you wrong understand. @Mr Zid

Comment: what u mean by front end? please clarify more . U can select different color and the price acccording to it will change . According to your question , this is what u need , else please correct the question

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You have created using Custom Options, but I need using Custom Field in .phtml file and price calculated based on time period difference of To and From field.

Comment: @VrajeshPatel did you found a solution for this?

Comment: No @mohith not yet. If you have then you can share.